# Angular pipe - Sorting without case sensitive

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting

I got this sorting pipe created in Angular project below. The result is
[image]
I need to sort "Accos, David pt., DIILL," The uppercase seems issue here.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy',
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any[], field: string): any[] {
    if (!array) return array;

    array = [...array];
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });

    return array;
  }
}
```

```html
 <ng-select
              [items]="accounts$ | async | orderBy: 'businessName'"
              [(ngModel)]="AccownerId"
              bindLabel="businessName"
              bindValue="id"
              [searchable]="false"
              id="Accowner"
            >
            </ng-select>
```

Comment: It works with update version ............................................................................       
  export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any[], field: any): any[] {
    if (!array) return array;

    array = [...array];
    array.sort((a, b) => a[field].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[field].toLowerCase()));

    return array;
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this case insensitive comparison:

```js
const options  = ["DIILL", "Accos", "David pt."];
        
options.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      return a.toLowerCase()
              .localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
  });
        
console.log(options);//["Accos", "David pt.", "DIILL"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated like this and working now.
    if (!array) return array;

    array = [...array];
    array.sort((a, b) => a[field].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[field].toLowerCase()));

    return array;